# Is the thread blocked when doing database operation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, threadpool

We have a WCF service (deployed on IIS) that makes expensive calls to database. It doesn't use any kind of asynchronous peogramming ( async\await).

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "StoreProcedure_NAME"; //Takes 6 seconds
        command.Connection = connection;
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        return dataset;
    }
}
```

Now, what will happen to the thread (I believe this is a wcf thread pool thread) making this call to the database during the 6 seconds of wait time. Is this thread blocking and taking up CPU cycles or will thread be in waiting state (waiting for an interrupt)?

Comment: A blocked thread does not take up CPU cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is blocked. There are `async` methods that are designed to return the thread to the listening pool, and retrieve a new (or the same) thread from the thread pool when completion of the task occurs. Non `async` methods will block your calling thread.

Comment: Is this thread taking up cpu cycles when it is blocked ( I am asking this as I read from here http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html that all the network calls are non-blocking)? I am using ADO.Net and the sqladapter doesn't expose async methods, is there any advantage(I know that it frees up WCF thread pool thread, but the new thread still blocks) in creating a new Task by myself and putting this code in the Task.Run? Thank you.

Comment: @SriHarshaVelicheti no - a thread must be doing work to be scheduled on the CPU and thus take up cycles. These threads effective get put into WAIT state... Not scheduled and idled (but blocking) until told to pick back up with the results of the long call. Instead of `Task.Run` you should take advantage of the `async` methods and callbacks.

Comment: Sorry If my question is naive (I am trying to get good understanding on multithreading), if I am using the async methods doesn't the BCL internally create a new thread on which the database call is done and gets blocked waiting for the interrupt?

Comment: @SriHarshaVelicheti the advantage to the async / BCL is that they use IO Completion Threads, low level OS threads to do the "blocking" work. They return the calling thread to the thread pool for others to use, and then when the IOCP is done, the same (or a different) thread is called out of the thread pool to resume executing your code with the result.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this thread blocking and taking up CPU cycles or will thread be in
>   waiting state (waiting for an interrupt)?

It is waiting for an interrupt and isn't consuming any CPU cycles. When you make an IO request, the request goes down all the way to the relevant device driver (or database process in your case), which is asynchronous by nature. Those IO requests are usually register an IRP (IO request packet). In the database case, the thread will block and wait for an interrupt in order to resume.

`SqlAdapter` is merely a wrapper for using [`SqlDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) (it's synchronous API, at least), which internally does expose asynchronous methods such as [`ReadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223681(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`NextResultAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223698(v=vs.110).aspx) using the `Task Asynchronous Pattern`. Instead of spinning up a new thread needlessly, use those API's.